# Entity Framework Cyrillic displayed as question marks

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am writing an application and I am using Entity Framework and MSSQL. I have some cyrillic data(Bulgarian, if that matters) in the database. Problem is when I try to read it from the program I get question marks(?????????) but when I try from SQL Management studio everything shows up fine. Collation is set to Cyrillic_General_CI_AS and I am using nvarchar for the columns I store cyrillic characters in.  I need your help. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. It turns out that the data that comes out of the database is perfectly fine. The problem was in the displaying. I was using a console project for testing and it apparently didn't like the cyrillic font. Changing the font of the console fixed my problem.