# Result of adding data by EntityFramework in Cyrillic is exclamation marks. SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, cyrillic

I have an web application where I just add some data by user inputs. However, when I test at real web server, I just see exclamation marks instead of "Привет".

```
using (DatabaseEntities context = new DatabaseEntities())
{
   name = "Человек";
   surname = "Привет";   
   Students student = new Students();
   apho.ID = ID;
   apho.Name = name;
   apho.Surname = surname;
   context.AddObject("Students", student);
   context.SaveChanges();                            
}
```

The result is for Name: "???????" and for Surname is: "??????"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried the solutions in these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640405/entity-framework-cyrillic-displayed-as-question-marks and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889438/entity-framework-c-sharp-insert-data-russian-encoding-problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mfanto is right. I use incorrect collation. A correct procedure is:

```
alter table Students
alter column
Surname Nvarchar(255)  COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS_KS not null
go
```

So my orders actions to see Russian letters in `SQL Server` through `Entity Framework` are:

1. Create Unicode fields(NVARCHAR)
2. Change collation(see above code(sql query)). Maybe it is not necessary as I've created Unicode fields.
3. Create **new** ADO.NET Entity Data Model as collated columns from SQL table  become in Entity Framework properties of classes are set to `Unicode - true`(I've seen these properties by clicking at properties in diagram)

That's it!:)